# How can I check enter key which is end of the barcode in asp.net by using iPad browser?

Tags: ios, asp.net, ipad, barcode, onkeypress

```
    <div id="texttt" style="font-size: 40px; color: white;">

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDene" CssClass="deneClass" runat="server" onkeypress="return noenter();"> </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDene" Text="Dene" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function noenter() {
            if (window.event.keyCode == 13 || window.event.keyCode == 10) {
                var x = $("#<%= txtDene.ClientID %>").val();
                while (x.length != 13) {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
                deneme();
            }
        }
        function deneme() {
            // I will write what I do in the code.
        }

    </script>

</form>
```

This code works for taking all barcode. Because Qrcode consists of 13 characters. And when barcode reader reads this code, for example, it reads only 4 characters. So I added this code part. It works. 
And these codes work in the PC, but if you are entering in the iPad browser, it does not work. What is the problem ?

Comment: in your while you are only checking for LF and not CR

Comment: I do not fully understand. Could you tell me more clearly?
What do I need to do as part of the code? Thank you from now.

Comment: Sorry I misread one line of your code.  have you put in breakpoints and debugged on a mac to find out where it is escaping?  Not sure but mac could be adding extra chars to the text.